# What sort of performance penalty does WINE cause?

Tags: linux, performance, wine, artemis-spaceship-bridge-simulator

I changed my 10+ year old Athlon XP (3000+) system from Windows XP to Linux Mint 17.1.  **I want to use WINE to play Artermis Bridge Simulator.**

My Athlon XP system used to be able to run an Artemis client.  I've installed the game and can run the client on the new Linux environment using WINE (with no configuration changes).  My only concern now is whether Linux WINE will run this application fast enough on my hardware.

Does anyone have a "rule of thumb" penalty that running Windows applications in WINE incur?  A 20% penalty might be OK, while 40% probably wouldn't.

Since posting my message I've done more research on my own.  I'll post what I've found as an answer but I very much appreciate other's thoughts too.

Comment: Just because you want to use this system to play games, doesn't make it on topic for gaming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this because "will this run it?" questions are off topic.

Comment: I was not asking whether it was running.  Please reread.  I'm asking whether I take a performance hit.  This may still be off-topic, if so is there a stack exchange I can use to ask the question?

Comment: Video games on **all systems** are on-topic so I don't know why running a video game on a Linux system could be considered off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct rule of thumb for all games. Some run brilliantly without any configuration at all, some run reasonably well and some won't run at all.

Theres far too many variables to give a specific answer.

Comment: Questions that are too broad to be answered should be flagged or voted on, not answered.

Comment: @Byte56 As far as I'm aware, there is no rule preventing anyone from answering any open question.  As for whether or not people think they *should*, well, feel free to vote on it.

Comment: @JohntheGreen I didn't say it was a rule. The problem is, when people ask off topic questions and they get answered, it encourages people to ask off topic questions anyway. Voting down correct answers isn't something I like to do, even if they shouldn't have been answered.

Comment: @Byte56 So long as the question is open and the answerer has something useful to contribute, I fail to see any problem with them contributing it.  If the question later ends up on hold, that should be warning enough to anyone who tries to use it as a precedent.  In this case, the answer happens to be correct and contain information relevant to the question that the asker apparently did not know.

Comment: @JohntheGreen Then contribute as a comment. The comment can also be used to explain why the question is off topic.

Comment: @Byte56 Or you can ask for clarification or more specificity.  I'll add some to my question.

Answer (score 1):

I have succeeded in installing and running the client software but haven't had a chance to hook up to a server and testing the fps and lagginess of the simulator.

[Artemis is rated "Platinum"^1](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=28792) on WINE.  Incidentally, you can search for other games at this site to determine their likelihood of working on WINE.

1 Platinum means it will install and run with little or no configuration changes.  No known showstopper issues.

I can post a follow-up with performance evaluation after my game next weekend.

Comment: Artemis played with WINE on Linux on an Athlon XP 3000+ (single core CPU) was a little sluggish but perfectly playable.  Some of the problem might have been an antique mouse.  I've purchased a new mouse to see if this helps.